# Did Tony Stark ever show any CEO-level communication skills at any point in the MCU?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man

It seems like Tony Stark's ability to lead is dependent on the plot at best. What are some cases where he actually shows decent communication skills that would be expected of a CEO? I would really like to be proven wrong, but my suspension of disbelief is lost with the new Spider-Man movie.

Spoiler about how I see the *Spider-Man: Homecoming* plot:

> The entire plot revolves around Stark's failure to communicate to Peter any details related to what he finds, i.e. Stark doesn't tell Peter that he contacted the FBI.

Comment: As I recall, he never *has* to show leadership skills. Obadiah ran his company for him, then Pepper did. Steve runs the Avengers, Fury runs SHIELD, Tony just builds and programs robots, and occasionally gives weapons to children.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh The closest that I could recall was deciding that they would go with the UN declaration in civil war.

Comment: You may recall that he relinquished his position as CEO to someone more suited for the role. Additionally, he's not the leader of the Avengers - just the guy bankrolling them.

Answer (score 10):

Just to pick at your premise, [Pepper Potts is CEO of Stark Industries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Man_2), not Tony, precisely because she’s good at everything that Tony’s not.

He became CEO of Stark Industries in the first place because he was a technical genius (he built the first Iron Man suit in a *CAVE!* In the *DESERT!* Out of *SCRAPS!!!!*), he was the boss’s son, and he was distracted enough to give Obadiah Stane room to run the company for his own gain. Once he got enough self-awareness and conscience, he handed the company over to someone with the required skills.

This leaves Tony free to do his own independent, wilful mercurial genius thing, which is sometimes incredibly effective (making the Spider-suit, saving New York from the Chitauri), but occasionally creates really dangerous situations (Ultron, Peter getting in the middle of an FBI sting on the Staten Island Ferry) that might not have occurred if he’d talked to a few people about what he was doing.

Answer (score 2):

He holds numerous "galas" to better the image/marketing of the company.  He puts on demonstrations of equipment to prospective buyers (Ironman 1 - the Jericho).  He holds a number of press conferences and gives interviews. Also, one could say his nurturing of his eccentric, aloof, playboy genius/philanthropist/... is marketing for the company itself.  He has many flaws but he is a skilled communicator when he deems it necessary to reach his ends.  Usually, he would rather everyone just saw how unbelievably smart he is and just went along with his plan.  Also, look at his communication to the Avengers and others on the initiative to register those with superpowers.  He may have polarized it, but he also won many over.